# Why is crond failing to run a non-root crontab on alpine linux?

Tags: linux, docker, cron, alpine-linux

I am having a nasty time running a non-root crontab file on Alpine Linux.

I've been through two other cron related posts and I don't have an answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working

https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Here is the setup.

My crontab looks like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * /opt/monitor/monitor.sh >> /var/log/monitor.log 2>&1
0 3 * * * /opt/monitor/monitor-log-clean.sh >> /var/log/monitor.log 2>&1
```

My Dockerfile is a little messy now, but only because I have been desperately trying to resolve this. It looks something like this. In short, I add SUID for crontab -e to work as other users, I create my user, I import my crontab file, and then I provide permissions to everything I can think of.

```
FROM alpine:3.5

# DEPENDENCY TO ALLOW USERS TO RUN crontab -e
RUN apk add --update busybox-suid

# I LIKE BASH
RUN apk --no-cache add bash bash-doc
RUN apk --no-cache add util-linux pciutils usbutils coreutils binutils findutils grep

#... lots of custom stuff ...    

# CREATE USER
RUN adduser -S robuser && \
    mkdir -p /home/robuser

# ADD ENTRY POINT
ADD src/entrypoint.sh /home/robuser/entrypoint.sh

# GIVE MY USER ACCESS
RUN mkdir /etc/cron.d
RUN echo "robuser" > /etc/cron.allow
RUN echo "" >> /etc/cron.allow
RUN chmod -R 644 /etc/cron.d

# ADD MY CRONTAB
RUN mkdir -p /var/spool/cron/crontabs
ADD ./src/crontab.conf /tmp/cloudwatch/crontab.conf
RUN crontab -u robuser /tmp/cloudwatch/crontab.conf

# DEBUG... GIVE MY USER ACCESS TO EVERYTHING
RUN chown -R robuser /etc/cron.d
RUN chmod -R 755 /etc/cron.d
RUN chown -R robuser /var/spool/cron
RUN chmod -R 744 /var/spool/cron
RUN chown robuser /var/spool/cron/crontabs
RUN chmod 744 /var/spool/cron/crontabs
RUN chown -R robuser /etc/crontabs
RUN chmod -R 744 /etc/crontabs
RUN chown robuser /etc/crontabs/robuser
RUN chmod -R 744 /etc/crontabs/robuser
RUN chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/robuser

# ADD MY MONITORING PROGRAM
RUN mkdir -p /opt/monitor
ADD src/monitor /opt/monitor
RUN mkdir -p /opt/monitor/.tmp && \
    chown -R robuser /opt/monitor && \
    chmod -R 700 /opt/monitor

RUN touch /var/log/entrypoint.log && \
    touch /var/log/monitor.log && \
    touch /var/log/cron.log && \
    touch /var/log/awslogs.log && \
    chown -R robuser /var/log

USER robuser

ENTRYPOINT /home/robuser/entrypoint.sh
```

meanwhile, my entrypoint.sh has this somewhere in it. I start the cron daemon as a background service and log to cron.log verbosely. I've also tried specifying -d 0 to get even more debug, but the didn't really add anything to the output.

```
#!/bin/bash

crond -b -l 0 -L /var/log/cron.log

#... lots of other startup stuff ...
```

An important point: If I don't switch to *robuser*, **everything works okay as root**.

If I check the *cron.log*, its pretty empty:

```
crond: crond (busybox 1.25.1) started, log level 0
crond: wakeup dt=45
crond: wakeup dt=60
crond: wakeup dt=60
```

Meanwhile, /var/log/monitor.log is completely empty (see crontab at the beginning of the post).

So crond is not printing any errors.

I've tried everything i can think of to debug this. There's no error message. It simply runs and never prints. A good suggestion was to simply my crontab.. but this also did not work:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * touch /tmp/test.txt
```

I've tried searching for other alpine containers who use non-root cron, but most people don't go through the trouble of getting their alpine containers to run non-root.

Does anyone have any further suggestions to help debug this?

Comment: This is a development question (DevOps). I am developing a docker container, and that docker container is using Alpine.

Please see the enormous number of other docker-related questions on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=docker

Answer (score 11):

`cron` itself should run as `root`, regardless of which user you want to use to run the jobs.

Indeed, when you run:

```
RUN crontab -u robuser /tmp/cloudwatch/crontab.conf
```

This will install a `crontab` for user `robuser`. When `cron` executes jobs from this particular `crontab`, it will automatically switch users to `robuser`. **However, `cron` can't switch users like that if it's not running as `root`, which is why you need to be running `cron` as root.**

So, to make `cron` work here, you'll need to remove this directive from your Dockerfile:

```
USER robuser
```

---

Note that you probably won't be out of the woods once you fix this issue: if you're using environment variables to pass AWS credentials to your monitoring scripts (it seems you're using AWS here), this won't work, because `cron` will remove those prior to switching users. This is largely a security feature in `cron` to avoid env-variable leakage to unprivileged users.

As an aside: I wrote an open-source crontab runner, [Supercronic](https://github.com/aptible/supercronic), specifically designed for container use cases, which fixes that (and you can run it as an unprivileged user just fine). If you get frustrated with regular `cron`, you could always give a shot.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. However, your suggestion of removing `USER robuser` means my entire container will not run as _robuser_. That includes my jboss server. As described by you, it sounds like running cron as _root_ and running my jboss server as _robuser_ is impossible.

Comment: @user3460784 If you wan to use regular `cron`, then indeed you probably can't run as it as an unprivileged user. However, you could run it as a privileged user, then use [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) to run jboss as an unprivileged user!

Comment: For anyone else still battling with this subject, I have managed to get the desired result by installing sudo and setting up sudoer entry for the robuser allowing them to run just a single shell script which starts crond.   I have it running ngnix as nginx and crond as root via sudo from nginx.

Answer (score 0):

coded the fix to run crond as non-root, basically crond was implemented in the busybox code base, and it called the function 'change_identity' which was invoking the syscall setgroups (the linux CAP_SETGID capability required commonly), to switch the job privilege into the normal user / group privilege, same as the job of the user, so crond process must be running as root.

I pushed the patched alpine onto docker hub:

```
geekidea/alpine-cron:3.7
geekidea/alpine-cron:3.8
geekidea/alpine-cron:3.9
geekidea/alpine-cron:3.10
```

A sample dockerfile:

```
FROM geekidea/alpine-cron:3.10

USER nobody
RUN mkdir /tmp/crontabs \
    && echo 'SHELL=/bin/sh' > /tmp/crontabs/nobody \
    && echo '* * * * * /tmp/nobody.sh' >> /tmp/crontabs/nobody \
    && echo 'echo "$(date) blahblahblah nobody" >> /tmp/nb-cron.log' > /tmp/nobody.sh \
    && chmod 0755 /tmp/nobody.sh \
    && chown -R nobody.nobody /tmp/crontabs/nobody

CMD ["crond", "-c", "/tmp/crontabs", "-l", "0", "-d", "0", "-f"]
```

see more: https://github.com/inter169/systs/blob/master/alpine/crond/README.md