# How To Run Cron As Non Root In Alpine

Tags: docker, cron, sh, devops, alpine-linux

I am trying to run a container with the following scripts:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest

USER root

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --no-cache add busybox-suid su-exec
RUN chmod u+s /sbin/su-exec

RUN groupadd -r -g 2001 myuser \
    && useradd -r -u 1001 -g myuser myuser

RUN mkdir /home/myuser \
    && chown myuser /home/myuser

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser entrypoint.sh /home/myuser/entrypoint.sh
COPY --chown=myuser:myuser cronjob /home/myuser/cronjob

USER myuser

RUN crontab /home/myuser/cronjob
WORKDIR /home/myuser
ENTRYPOINT["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start cron daemon.
su-exec root crond -f -l 8

# Start application.
```

I have read that elevating privileges is not good practice. Therefore, I wish to eliminate usage of `su-exec` + `chmod u+s /sbin/su-exec` in my script. I tried `su` and `sudo` as well but they were asking for `root` password so I switched to `su-exec` instead. I needed to elevate privilege because `crond` does not run properly without starting it as `root`. This container will be run in Kubernetes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crond` is now running as `myuser` after following the answer below.

https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/381#issuecomment-621946699

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest

USER root

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --no-cache add dcron libcap

RUN groupadd -r -g 2001 myuser \
    && useradd -r -u 1001 -g myuser myuser

RUN mkdir /home/myuser \
    && chown myuser /home/myuser

RUN chown myuser:myuser /usr/sbin/crond \
    && setcap cap_setgid=ep /usr/sbin/crond

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser cronjob /home/myuser/cronjob
RUN crontab /home/myuser/cronjob

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser entrypoint.sh /home/myuser/entrypoint.sh

USER myuser

WORKDIR /home/myuser
ENTRYPOINT["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start cron daemon.
crond -b -l 8

# Start application.
```

Comment: When I try this kind of solution I get `setpgid: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: As I understood there is an issue when using non root account as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45280550/5689995 . There is a solution offered to start using alternative instead of Crontab for containers.

Comment: As a workaround for the `Operation not permitted` issue, I run `crond` as non-1 PID by using an entrypoint script [as described here](https://github.com/dubiousjim/dcron/issues/13#issuecomment-340382335). It works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you are trying to achive but I would do it on OS-level.

You can create a cronjob to execute something in your container is this would help.
Try to use something like this:

```
/usr/bin/docker exec <container_name> <command>
```

When you would like to have some logging you could do:

```
/usr/bin/docker exec <container_name> <command> > <path_to_log>
```

Answer (score 0):

like @and-finally on bitnami/gitea docker image I cannot use setpcap as it generates a `setpgid: Operation not permitted`

my solution was to **slightly modify** the old but robust http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html .

If `crond` is not ran with uid=0 it does not try to change the user, and so run the cron as the current user.

So on my bitnami/gitea wich run gitea with uid=1001 I run crond with the same user, wich is perfect for execution cron jobs in `/etc/cron.d` like:

```
* 3 * * *                  my_custom_script
```

It is very easy to modify but if you don't want to do it yourself it is hosted at https://github.com/eltorio/dcron

For example this is my custom bitnami/gitea Docker image.

```
FROM bitnami/gitea:latest as busyboxbuilder
USER root
RUN cd / \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential curl libntirpc-dev
COPY busybox/busybox-1.36.1.tar.bz2 /busybox-1.36.1.tar.bz2
RUN cd / &&  tar -xjvf  busybox-1.36.1.tar.bz2
COPY busybox/busybox.config /busybox-1.36.1/.config
RUN cd /busybox-1.36.1/ && make install

FROM bitnami/gitea:latest as dcronbuilder
USER root
RUN cd / \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential curl libntirpc-dev git
RUN mkdir -p /etc/cron.d && chown -R 1001 /etc/cron.d
RUN git clone https://github.com/eltorio/dcron.git \
    && cd dcron \
    && make CRONTAB_GROUP=gitea CRONTABS=/tmp/crontabs CRONSTAMPS=/tmp/cronstamps

FROM bitnami/gitea:latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update -y && apt install -y --no-install-recommends vim
RUN mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/custom/public
COPY --chmod=0755 libgitea.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/libgitea.sh
COPY --chmod=0755 gitea-env.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/gitea-env.sh
COPY --chmod=0755 autobackup.sh /usr/local/bin/autobackup
COPY --from=busyboxbuilder /busybox-1.36.1/_install/bin/busybox /bin/busybox
RUN ln -svf /bin/busybox /usr/sbin/sendmail \
    && chmod ugo+x /opt/bitnami/scripts/libgitea.sh \
    && chmod ugo+x /opt/bitnami/scripts/gitea-env.sh \
    && chmod ugo+x /usr/local/bin/autobackup 
COPY --from=dcronbuilder /opt/bitnami/gitea/dcron/crond /usr/sbin/crond
RUN mkdir -p /etc/cron.d && chown -R 1001 /etc/cron.d && chmod 0755 /usr/sbin/crond

WORKDIR /opt/bitnami/gitea
USER 1001
```